# Authenticate with Google as a specific User ID

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I have set up Google Drive UI integration with my web app. When a user chooses to create a new file in Drive using my app, they are sent to

```
https://[mysite]?state={"folderId": "...", "action": "create", "userId":"..."}
```

---

I am signed in to multiple Google accounts (A and B) in my browser.

Account A opts to create a file, and is sent to my app with `"userId": "[A's user id]"` in the url.

However, with the `gapi.auth2` JS library:

```
authInstance.signIn()
// Listen for sign in, and then:
authInstance.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token
```

Returns an access token for Account B.

This causes 404 errors when I try to create a file in `folderId`, which is only accessible to Account A.

How can my app authenticate with Google as the specific `userId` that opted to create a file?

---

The docs for [Drive UI Integration](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-create) do not seem to cover this issue, and the docs for [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) do not (as far as I can tell) provide a way to specify which account I want to sign in with (except through broad filters like "use a specific G Suite domain").

---

**Update**: The [HTTP Google OAuth docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#formingtheurl) allow the client to specify a `login_hint`, which is an "`email address` or `sub` identifier" – it is not entirely clear what a "`sub` identifier" is. And, strangely, the [Javascript API docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetauthresponseincludeauthorizationdata) imply that `login_hint` is a response parameter, not something I can set.

**Update 2** `userId` is an opaque Google-provoded integer value that I don't recognise. My app, Including the Drive upload, is fully client-side in JS and has no long-term data storage.

Comment: Is it the browser JS, or your web app which is doing the GDrive insert? Is "userID" the Google account ID, or some opaque id in your own app? Does your app hold user info, and if so does it include the Google account ID,or gmail address?

Comment: @pinoyyid updated to clarify thanks.